# Weird inflection of the verb in ta form - たれた

Tags: verbs, conjugations, nouns, light-novel, inflection

I'm a beginner in Japanese; and as an exercise I've tried to translate a sentence from the LN. While I do realize that I've bit more that I can chew, I wish to at least try :)

The sentence that I am struggling with is (with emboldened specific point)

その中で**放たれた時空**の大魔法は、日本のとある高校の教室で炸裂した。

As far as I can tell, emboldened part means (roughly) 'was released in space-time/exploded space time'. I don't really understand the たれた suffix. We have 放 in past tense, TA form used to modify 時空. I would expect this word to have った　suffix. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you learned passive voice yet?

Comment: No, I did not. While I was searching for a hint, I've come across the passive voice, but it only seems to be `rareru`... And it seems to have my answer here -> https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-passive-form-rareru/

Godan, with passive form of tsu verb.

Thanks, you have really helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

放たれた【はなたれた】 is [放つ【はなつ】](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A4) in the past passive form. (Note that [放す【はなす】](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%94%BE%E3%81%99) is a different verb with the same kanji.)

- 放つ: "to unleash (something)"
- 放った: "unleashed (something)" (past)
- 放たれる: "is unleashed" (passive)
- 放たれた: "was unleashed" (past passive)

It modifies not only 時空 but 時空の大魔法 as a whole. Here, 時空(の)魔法 is a category of magic often referred to as [Time Magic](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Magic).

> その中で放たれた時空の大魔法は、日本のとある高校の教室で炸裂した。
> The great time(-space) magic unleashed in it exploded in a classroom of a certain high school in Japan.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jimmy Yang](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/41067/jimmy-yang), he has pointed me in the right direction. The answer is:

Passive voice of a godan verb with a `つ` suffix as seen here https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-passive-form-rareru/

which then is changed to `た` form to be used as a noun modifier.